# I want to be able to pull login info from a CSV to use as parameters for the redfish object

Tags: python, object, variables

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # When running on the server locally use the following commented values
    # iLO_https_url = "blobstore://."
    # iLO_account = "None"
    # iLO_password = "None"

    # When running remotely connect using the iLO secured (https://) address, 
    # iLO account name, and password to send https requests
    # iLO_https_url acceptable examples:
    # "https://10.0.0.100"
    # "https://f250asha.americas.hpqcorp.net"
    iLO_https_url = "https://10.0.0.100"
    iLO_account = "admin"
    iLO_password = "password"

    # Create a REDFISH object
    try:
        REDFISH_OBJ = RedfishObject(iLO_https_url, iLO_account, iLO_password)
    except ServerDownOrUnreachableError as excp:
        sys.stderr.write("ERROR: server not reachable or doesn't support " \
                                                                "RedFish.\n")
        sys.exit()
    except Exception as excp:
        raise excp

    ex4_reset_server(REDFISH_OBJ)
    REDFISH_OBJ.redfish_client.logout()
```

Above is the "login" part of the script im writing. In this part, `REDFISH_OBJ = RedfishObject(iLO_https_url, iLO_account, iLO_password)`, I would like to replace `iLO_https_url` with a variable whose value would be pulled from a simple CSV file. The CSV would have 3 columns...ip, username,pwd.

I'm trying to execute the other part of the script, not shown here, on every IP in the CSV file. I need to do this in python.

Comment: You seem to know what you want to do. What prevents you from doing it? What is your question?

Comment: this one line has a hard coded URL in it.... (iLO_https_url = "https://10.0.0.100") i want to use a variable instead of the hard coded URL. A CSV file would be holding the IPs that the varible would use. Im certainly no pro.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the open() function with the split() function.

Try something like this:

`with open("data.csv", encoding="utf-8") as csv_file:
    iLO_account, iLO_password, iLO_https_url = csv_file.readline().split(",")`

If you are separating your entries with new line breaks, simply replace the `","`, with a `"\n"`

Comment: bad idea: use `csv` module instead (note that the last field will have a linefeed at the end...)

Comment: iLO_account, iLO_password, iLO_https_url = [x.strip() for x in csv_file.readline().split(",")] if you want to remove whitespace around the csv fields.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre depending on the use case is the `csv` module simply overkill. If he only wants to store and safe this data for internal use this method is fine. However if those are unknown files the `csv` module is better suited. Then you also have to deal with the inconsistencies of csv files, since there is no standard for csv.

Comment: I will try all these suggestions and let you all know which worked best for me... You guys are great and so timely!! Thanks so much!